# Migrate from UI Router 1.x to 2

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to figure out how to migrate our current code using UI Router 1.x with AngularJS to 2 but I can't seem to find enough examples. The documentation on their site is pretty lame and doesn't really help.

What I'd like to know is:

1. How to use the abstract state? Or does 2 support it at all?
2. How to do parent-child state?
3. How to use resolve?

Here's my existing code that uses UI Router 1.x:

```
$stateProvider
    .state("app",
    {
        abstract: true,
        url: "",
        template: "<ui-view/>",
        controller: "appController",
        controllerAs: "vm",
        resolve: {
            currentUser: ["$stateParams", "security", function ($stateParams, security) {
                return security.getIdentity();
            }]
        }
    })
    .state("app.test",
    {
        data: { title: "Test" },
        url: "/Test",
        templateUrl: "app/controllers/test/test.html",
        controller: "testController",
        controllerAs: "vm"
    }),
    .state("app.test.child",
        {
            data: { title: "TestChild" },
            url: "/TestChild",
            views: {
                "@app": {
                    templateUrl: "app/controllers/testChild/template.html",
                    controller: "testChildController",
                    controllerAs: "vm"
                }
            }
        })
```

I'm having trouble converting the above code to use UI Router 2.

Comment: have you go through [official migration guide](https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/migrate-to-1_0)?